ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Django-Azure
I'm trying to get an SSO authentication in my django admin app and I have those lines :

AZURE_AUTH = {
    "CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CLIENT_SECRET": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "REDIRECT_URI": "http://localhost:8000/admin",
    "SCOPES": [""],
    "CA_BUNDLE": "false",
    "AUTHORITY": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/450c4b37-1c5f-4415-a413-c83c13fd5316/",   
   # "PUBLIC_URLS": ["<public:view_name>",]  
   # "PUBLIC_PATHS": 
}
LOGIN_URL = "/azure_auth/login"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("azure_auth.backends.AzureBackend",)


But when I put my localhost URL I have a lots of redirects in my terminal and I cannot connect to my SSO account because of too many redirects, and yes i tried to disable cookies :(
Does this happened to anyone?
Let me know if you've any idea

The issue of too many redirects typically occurs when there's a misconfiguration in the authentication settings or when the redirect URI doesn't match the one registered in the Azure AD app. Double-check that the redirect URI specified in your Django settings (REDIRECT_URI) matches exactly with the one configured in your Azure AD app registration. Additionally, ensure that the Django app is running on the specified localhost port (8000) and that there are no conflicting redirects or middleware causing the issue
